# ¿Cómo obtener las tablas relacionadas a una función en postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hay alguna forma de obtener las tablas que están relacionadas a una función en PostgreSQL? existe la opción para  las vistas, con el Query:

```
select * from  information_schema.view_table_usage
```

Para obtener todas las funciones encontré:  `select * from  information_schema.routines`, sin embargo ésta no muestra las tablas que están relacionadas a cada función.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Pues esta consulta te puede dar algo de informacion aunque no es fiable

```
SELECT word, proname
from (
       SELECT regexp_split_to_table(REPLACE(prosrc, ';', ' '), '\s+') as word , proname
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
              JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p
                   ON pronamespace = n.oid
       WHERE nspname = 'public'
     ) in_routine
WHERE word  IN (
   SELECT tablename
   FROM   pg_tables
   WHERE  schemaname = 'public'
   );
```

No es fiable y me explico.
Lo que hace es coger la función o *routine* como texto. Separa las palabras por espacio y comprueba si cada palabra es una tabla del esquema *public*.

No es fiable por que si en el código de la funcion, la tabla aparece como `schema.my_table`, al tener un '.' no lo va a encontrar.

Se puede mejorar la expresión regular `regexp_split_to_table(REPLACE(prosrc, ';', ' '), '\s+')` ya que ahora le he puesto un replace feo. si consigues que te separe palabras por `. ( ;` y signos típicos, puede que te funcione.

No es lo mejor, pero espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta [extension](https://pgxn.org/dist/plpgsql_check), especificamente la función:
`plpgsql_show_dependency_tb`